# @font-face ligatures missing

Tags: css, font-face, truetype, eot

I am using an embedded typeface using the following code:

```
 @font-face {font-family: 'PFDinTextPro-Regular';src: url('../webfonts/15B214_0.eot');src: url('../webfonts/15B214_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../webfonts/15B214_0.woff') format('woff'),url('../webfonts/15B214_0.ttf') format('truetype'),url('../webfonts/15B214_0.svg#wf') format('svg');}
 @font-face {font-family: 'PFDinTextPro-Bold';src: url('../webfonts/15B214_1.eot');src: url('../webfonts/15B214_1.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../webfonts/15B214_1.woff') format('woff'),url('../webfonts/15B214_1.ttf') format('truetype'),url('../webfonts/15B214_1.svg#wf') format('svg');}


 @font-face {font-family: 'PFDinTextPro-Italic';src: url('../webfonts/15B217_0.eot');src: url('../webfonts/15B217_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../webfonts/15B217_0.woff') format('woff'),url('../webfonts/15B217_0.ttf') format('truetype'),url('../webfonts/15B217_0.svg#wf') format('svg');}

body { font-family: PFDinTextPro-Regular;
         background-image: url(../img/MH_blue.png); 
         }
```

But a strange thing is happening. All the ligature combination letters are missing. Such as, the word "stuff" is showing as "stu".

what could the issue be?

Comment: What service you use for make web fonts? http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ ?

Comment: Can you give us a live demo of what's happening? I have a similar setup to this in a site I'm designing right now (embedded typeface) and haven't run into any issues (other than font size affecting quality of font appearance).

Comment: This was a downloaded font from myfonts.com. The problem appeared in firefox 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to re-download a version of the font from the supplier choosing "Please choose Keep Open Type Layout (complete character set will be automatically selected) and download the kit"

Now the ligatures are displaying.

Alternatively, adding `-moz-font-feature-settings: "calt=0,liga=0";` would have made the characters appear regularly:

```
@font-face {font-family: 'PFDinTextPro-Regular';src: url('../webfonts/174F15_0.eot');src: url('../webfonts/174F15_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../webfonts/174F15_0.woff') format('woff'),url('../webfonts/174F15_0.ttf') format('truetype');}
```

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future, note that as of FF 15 (I think) the syntax has now changed, and you'll need to use this:

-moz-font-feature-settings: "liga=0";
-moz-font-feature-settings: "liga" 0;